# Restlet Server Resource in Blueprint (Apache Karaf)

Tags: restlet, apache-karaf, blueprint-osgi

I am using **Apache Karaf** and **Blueprint** , I am having a hard time integrating these technologies with **Restlet**. I found the `org.restlet.ext.osgi` library and this tutorial [OSGi at REST](https://bryanhunt.wordpress.com/2011/06/30/osgi-at-rest/) that uses **Service Component Runtime**.

So a sample ServerResource would be

```
public SampleResource extends ServerResource {
    @Get
    public Representation represent(Representation representation){
         /* Do something crazy here */
    }
}
```

to register it to a resource it must be attached to a router or an application

```
public class SampleRouter extends Router {
    public SampleRouter {
        super();
        attach("/sampleroute", SampleResource.class);
    }
}
```

attaching it using `SampleResource.class` is quite troublesome if I have dependencies injected using **Blueprint**

```
public SampleResource extends ServerResource {

    private InjectedDependency dependency; /* Injected using Blueprint */

    @Get
    public Representation represent(Representation representation){
         /* Do something crazy here */
    }
}
```

How can I attach a `ServerResource` even if I have injected **Blueprint Services** or are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

Use Apache camel for defining Restlet integrations. In fact their new REST DSL is easy to use.
See
http://camel.apache.org/rest-dsl.html
http://camel.apache.org/restlet.html

Camel has a blueprint schema defined so you get tooling support and help with your blueprint definitions. That is the way I would go if you want to use blueprint using Restlet in Karaf.

Edit:
Here is a barebone example of Restlet in Camel Blueprint:

```
<camelContext>
  <route id="RS_RestletDemo">
    <from uri="restlet:http://localhost:7000/demo/{id}" />
    <transform>
      <simple>Request type : ${header.CamelHttpMethod} and ID : ${header.id}</simple>
    </transform>
  </route> 
</camelContext>
```

For more information look at the Camel documentation. I think to convert your code or create something based on your requirements is a good exercise for you to do in order to learn it.

Comment: Would you mind giving some examples or better translate the snippet above using `Apache Camel`?